# Как передать информацию из input в div онлайн и без кнопки?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Подскажите как передать информацию из input-form в box. То есть я набиваю текст в инпуте и он тут же отображается в box. Заранее благодарю.

```
<body>
<input type="text" class="input-form">
<div class="box"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 5):

```js
    window.onload = function () { // При загрузке документа
        let text = document.getElementsByClassName('input-form')[0]; // Получаем первый элемент с классом input-form
        let box = document.getElementsByClassName('box')[0]; // Получаем первый элемент с классом box
        text.oninput = function () { // Отслеживаем ввод в поле input
            box.innerText = this.value;  // В box выводим вводимый текст.
        }
    }
```

```html
<body>
<input type="text" class="input-form">
<div class="box"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: `getElementsByClassName('input-form')[0]` — случайно не у W3Schools подсматриваете такое?) Его можно заменить на `document.querySelector('.input-form');` А `window.onload` может задержать выполнение, пока все картинки, стили и внешние скрипты не загрузятся...

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME Стар я для подсматривания. Расчёт был на то, что могло быть много подобных элементов. Тогда уж `querySelectorAll`. Так правильнее, но это скорее привычка.  А по поводу window.onload, что-то я не вижу тут картинок. Вы разве видите в вопросе картинки? Ну так до любого момента можно докопаться. Это я Вам точно говорю. Недавно только Ваши работы смотрел.

Comment: Если замечаете у меня косяки... не стесняйтесь тыкать в них, буду только рад исправить) С window.onload... не то, что докапываюсь, просто часто замечал в ваших ответах. Вы может хорошо понимаете, о чем он, а кто-то может не до конца поняв, скопировать его к себе и что-то сломать)

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME Ну тут, Вы, к сожалению, правы. Надо, наверно, действительно для пользователей либо давать пояснения, либо уж лучше `DOMContentLoaded`. Приму к сведению, спасибо. Я, если честно, не фанат делать замечания, мне кажется, что если ответ решает задачу (без явного вреда), то он имеет место быть. А способы и подходы у каждого всегда модифицируются. И Вы, наверно, так же как и я, в ходе познавания новых методологий, стараетесь переписать старые ответы, или дополнить их новой информацией. Я искренне благодарен Вам, что Вы в корректном формате поправили меня.

Answer (score 2):

```js
document.getElementById('inputid').addEventListener // добавляем событие
  (
    'input', // на ввод
    function name(e){ // задаём имя, чтобы потом можно было сбросить  выполнение функции на событие
      document.getElementById('boxid').innerText = this.value; // задаем текстом div'a значение поля, которое "прослушиваем"
    }
  )
```

```html
<input id="inputid" type="text" class="input-form">
<div id="boxid" class="box"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Используй [JQ](https://jquery.com/download/)

```js
$('input[type="text"]').keydown(({currentTarget})=>{
    const txt = $(currentTarget).val();
    $('div.box').text(txt);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Просто так захотелось

```js
const $ = (selector) => document.querySelector(selector);
$('.input-form').oninput = function(){ $('.box').innerText = this.value }
```

```html
<body>
<input type="text" class="input-form">
<div class="box"></div>
</body>
```